# How do i insert blank rows after every new rows in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I've a data

```
 0002 100789  Clearing charges       1000.00-  Pending
 0002 239890  Cheque bounce            20.00   client accepted
 0001 789652  Export docs             200.00   Bank of Italy charges
```

Output file should be

```
0002 100789  Clearing charges       1000.00-  Pending

0002 239890  Cheque bounce            20.00   client accepted

0001 789652  Export docs             200.00    Bank of Italy charges
```

my code

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_fwf("C:\\csv_in\\back_trans.csv",widths=[4,9,16,15,23],header=None)
result=df.to_string(index=False,header=None)
new_file=open("C:\\csv_out\\back_trans.csv",mode="a+",encoding="utf-8")
new_file.writelines(result)
for line in new_file:
    print(line)
new_file.close()
```

Creating blank rows, which function I've to use. Please throw some lights on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.to_csv()` to make your life a litter easier (and your code a little faster).

`df.to_csv()` then has an argument `line_terminator`. This controls what separates one row from another in the resulting `.csv` file.

How exactly a newline is encoded depends on your operating system. We can use `os.linesep` to find out the newline character for your OS (I can see here that you're running windows, but using `os.linesep` would be considered good practice anyway, and colleagues running a different OS will thank you).

Here's an MWE:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 3))) 

df.to_csv("C:\\csv_out\\back_trans.csv", line_terminator=os.linesep*2)
```

This gave me the file contents as

```
❯ cat C:\\csv_out\\back_trans.csv 
,0,1,2

0,4,3,4

1,1,1,8

2,4,7,1

3,3,3,7

4,8,5,0

5,7,5,3

6,1,1,0

7,0,3,4

8,1,7,1

9,1,2,9
```

Comment: my output file above mentioned like. not comma separated file

Comment: You can change what separates the values with the ```sep``` argument in ```df.to_csv```. Eg. ```df.to_csv("C:\\csv_out\\back_trans.csv", line_terminator=os.linesep*2, sep=" ")```